# Array of constant size, known at compile time.. but in the derived classes only

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, literals

I have those classes `A` and `B` and more..

```
class A : public O
{
    static const int _nbItems = 3;
    ...
};

class B : public O
{
    static const int _nbItems_mine_mine = 7800;
    ...
};

...
```

They all inheritate from the *abstract* parent class `O` which *knows* how to manage an `Item`s collection and won't let the kids play around with it as they want..

```
class O
{
private:

    // The kids won't be able to access this structure directly for it is carefully updated
    Item _items[size];        

    // (I mean.. *truly*, look :)
    void update() // called by the clock
    {
       for(int i(0); i < size; ++i) /* things involving */ _items[i] /*, its environment etc.*/
    };

protected:

    // They may set their items this way only:
    void setItemNo(int id, BuildInformation const& buildInfo)
    {
        /* 
         * check whether or not the item has already been added..
         * perform everything that must be done to welcome a new item..
         * well.. 'so many things the kids do not need to be aware of.
         */

        // and then:
        _items[id] = Item(buildInfo);

    };

   // .. retrieve information about the current state of their items this way only:
   SomeInformation getItemState(int id) const {return _items[id].currentState();};

   // .. and eventually change some of their properties this way only:
   void setItemProperty(int id, Property const& newProperty)
   {
     /* checks, updates, eventual repercussions on other items and the environment */
     _items[id].setProperty(newProperty);
   };
};
```

What can I use as a structure for `O::_items` that could get all the stored `Item`s allocated on the *stack*? It should be possible since its size is ultimately known at compile time, shouldn't it?

Put it anoter way: How could I make the informations `*nbItems*` find their way up to `O::size` in a fashion that let the compiler know they are still literal constants, even yet undefined in `O`?

---

PS: By the time `O` is written, I am obviously not aware of all the possible derived classes it may have one day.

Comment: Is there any reason that `O` cannot be a template class parameterized on `size`?

Comment: Make `O` a template. `template<size_t size> class O { Item _item[size]; } `, then your derived classes can derive from `O<3>` or `O<7800>`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Ooh, maybe not! Let me think further on this one.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a base class `O` without the array:

```
class O
{
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual Item * data() const = 0;

    void update()
    { 
        for (Item * p = data(), * e = p + size(); p != e; ++p)
        {
            // use *p
        }
    }

public:
    virtual ~O() {}
};
```

Then an intermediate derived class:

```
template <size_t N> class OWithArray : public O
{
public:
    static size_t const nItems = N;
private:
    Item items[N];
    virtual size_t size() const { return nItems; }
    virtual Item * data() const { return items; }
};
```

And then have all your actual derived classes derive from an intermediate class:

```
class A : public OWithArray<3>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Sweet, and why not even making `O` directly a template as T.C and Charles Bailey suggest?

Comment: @Iago-lito: Well, you said that `O` in an abstract class (although in your example it is not). Without more complete details it's not obvious whether you need `O` to be an actual class rather than a class template.

Comment: @Iago-lito Because if you make `O` a template directly, then `O<3>` and `O<7800>` are distinct types, so `A` and `B` won't have a common base class. This gives them a common base class.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Yeah, `O` does have virtual methods, but the snippet was actually pretty long.

Comment: @T.C.: Crystal clear. Actually in the actual project, there is already an intermediate class that I can tranform this way I think.

Comment: Note that the compiler may not be able optimize the `for` loop, as `p != data() + size()` includes two virtual method calls, which in principle could have side effects. They are executed once for each cycle. It might make sense to cache the result before the loop is entered.

Answer (score 1):

```
class O {
  private:
     Item* items;
     unsigned int number_of_items

  protected:
     O (Item* itemsstorage, unsigned int n_items)
     : items (itemsstorage), number_of_items (n_items) { ... }

  // you'll probably need something like the following
  // make it private rather than using "= delete" prior to C++11
     O & operator = (const O &) = delete;
     O (const O &) = delete;
     O (O &&) = delete;

  public:
     virtual ~O () { }
}

class A : public O {
  private:
     enum { howManyItems = 3 };
     Item allMyItems [howManyItems];

  public:
     A () : O (allMyItems, howManyItems) { }
}
```

Or templatize `A` to make it more flexible:

```
template<unsigned int N>
class A : public O {
  private:
     Item allMyItems [N];

  public:
     A () : O (allMyItems, N) { }
}
```

Note that you **do** need a virtual destructor in class `O` if you polymorphically treat `A`'s as `O`'s (means: you definitely will, unless you are absolutely 100% sure that you won't)!!!!

Comment: You'll also need to supply assignment operators for this.

Comment: You need to prevent copying and moving and assigning `O's`, I guess.

Comment: Yeah but this way, `A` is still able to do anything it wants with its `Item`s, isn't it? Nothing prevents it to call `allMyItems[0].setProperty("fancyOne")` on its own and screw up then the whole process?

Comment: Ah, with "kids" you mean the derived classes. Combine the approach with the other answer by making my `A` an `OwithArray` and deriving your `A` from `OwithArray`.

Comment: I think this is it now.. Thanks! ^ ^

Comment: If you can use C++11 features, I would prefer `static constexpr std::size_t howManyItems = 3;` over the `enum` trick.